# VLC win32Compile error

Tags: winapi, compilation, vlc

I'm trying to compile the latest release of vlc for Windows using this tutorial: https://wiki.videolan.org/Win32Compile/

I'm compiling with Ubuntu 13.04 and using the host triplet i686-w64-mingw32.
Everything runs fine until "Building VLC". This is the error:

---

```
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/nuno/tpplugins/vlc/win32/modules'
CCLD     libavio_plugin.la
/home/nuno/tpplugins/vlc/contrib/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libavutil.a(time.o): In function `av_usleep':
/home/funman/vlc-git/contrib/win32/ffmpeg/libavutil/time.c:60: undefined reference to `_nanosleep'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

### make[4]: *** [libavio_plugin.la] Error 1

Any ideas how to solve this? My gcc version is 4.8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Recently had the same issue.

To resolve, try the following steps:-

```
sudo apt-get install yasm
cd contrib/win32
make .ffmpeg
make .gnutls
```

Then try to continue your make of vlc and hopefully all will be well.

Comment: it's still not working. Could you tell me the operating system that you used? Did you follow the tutorial win32compile exactly or did you do something else? thanks!